# Please help to convert SQL-query to Elasticsearch-query

Tags: sql, elasticsearch

How to convert SQL-query like this

```
select IndexA.* from IndexA where IndexA.NAME like ('%stics%') and IndexA.ID in (1,2,3,4)
```

in Elasticsearch-query(v6.x) ?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
POST /IndexA/_search -d '
{
"query" : {
 "bool" : { 
 "must" : [
    {
        "wildcard" : {
                "name" : "*stics*"
        } 
    },
    { 
        "terms" : {
            "_id" : ["1", "2", "3"] 
        }
     }
   ]
  }
 }
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

In ES7, this can be done simply as follows:

```
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -XPOST 127.0.0.1:9200/_xpack/sql/translate?pretty -d '{"query" : "select IndexA.* from IndexA where IndexA.NAME like ('%stics%') and IndexA.ID in (1,2,3,4)"}'
```